# Ubuntu is using a proxy although it's disabled in the settings

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, configuration, proxy

I have a problem with the proxy settings in Xubuntu 14.04 32-bit. Sometimes I need a proxy so I apply it to "/etc/profile", "/etc/environment" and "/etc/apt/apt.conf". If I don't need the proxy I comment these lines out like this:

(environment & profile)

```
#export http_proxy=http://*****:*****@proxy:8080
#export https_proxy=http://*****:*****@proxy:8080
#export ftp_proxy=http://*****:*****@proxy:8080
#export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
#export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
#export FTP_PROXY=$ftp_proxy
```

(apt.conf)

```
 #Acquire::http::proxy "http://*****:*****@proxy:8080";
 #Acquire::https::proxy "https://*****:*****@proxy:8080";
 #Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://*****:*****@proxy:8080";
```

Actually I don't need this so the config-files are like shown above.
The problem is that wget (and git) still "want to use the proxy":

```
 root@xubuntu-portable:~# wget something.com/index.html
 --2015-07-17 12:40:06--  http://something.com/index.html
 Auflösen des Hostnamen »proxy (proxy)«... 10.100.10.1
 Verbindungsaufbau zu proxy (proxy)|10.100.10.1|:8080...
```

(sorry, it's not in English)

The interesting point is that I configured Firefox so it uses the system settings. As you can see in the question I can use the browser and I can access everything with the browser.

Any help?

EDIT:

The output of "gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy":

```
 org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
 org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
 org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '::1']
 org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 0
 org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 0
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http host ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
 org.gnome.system.proxy.https host ''
 org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 0
```

Comment: You may have configured a system-wide proxy via gnome: check under System Settings --> Network --> Network Proxy or from the command line using `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy`

Comment: @steeldriver: Thank you very much. Unfortunatly this doesn't work too. It's a very strange problem.

Comment: have you checked `/etc/wgetrc` or `~/.wgetrc`? to disable proxy for wget use `use_proxy = off `  in any of those files. By the way `#` does not comment a line in `apt.conf`.

Comment: @souravc: Thank you, I checked this. The line `use_proxy = on` is a comment. In addition I don't think this is the problem, because `git clone` does not work either.
Is it possible to comment a line in `apt.conf`?

Comment: line comment in `apt.conf` can be done using `//` in front of a line.

Comment: @souravc: OK, so it's like in coding...

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget --no-proxy something.com/index.html`
Check settings for git.

Ant try reboot PC after you comment proxy config file.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a long-time solution to the problem. And I rebooted and checked the files twice.